# Easiest way to sub-string the following strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

The strings will look like something like this:

```
"Hello John and Hi Anne"
```

or

```
"Hello Daniel and Hi Kraig"
```

I want to get names from the strings; for example

```
var name1 = "John"
var name2 = "Anne"
```

"

`Hello`, `Hi`, `and` won't change, only the names will.

How can I do this operation in Javascript? I don't want to count indices really.

Edit: In name variable there is no space, i.e. name can't be "John Doe".

Comment: can be name John Doe ..eg. Hi John Doe?

Comment: No but thanks for thinking this.

Comment: If you have a consistent pattern, you can use regular expressions to do the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var nameString = "Hello John and Hi Anne";
var names = nameString.match(/Hello (.*) and Hi (.*)/);
console.log(names[1]); // John
console.log(names[2]); // Anne
```

Comment: I was just about to post something similar, though my regex was slightly different: `/^Hello (.+) and Hi (.+)$/`

Comment: Thank you very much. If I want to use your code in a function what shall I do? For example myfunc(inputStr) where inputStr="Hello John and Hi Anne"

Comment: @nikamed It would be basically the same: `var names = inputStr.match(...); return [names[1], names[2]]; `

Answer (score 3):

```
var array = "Hello Daniel and Hi Kraig".split(' ')
var name1 = array[1]
var name2 = array[array.length - 1]
```

Comment: @daremachine pointed out that 'name' could have several words.

Comment: @sobolevn Actually, it can't - see OP's comment and edit. This answer is a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp to get the names.

```
var string = "Hello John and Hi Anne";
var matches = string.match(/Hello\s+([a-zA-Z]+)\s+and\s+Hi\s+([a-zA-z]+)/);
console.log(matches[1], matches[2]);
```

`\s+` means one or more white char

`[a-zA-Z]+` means one or more char from a-z and A-Z

Answer (score 1):

Use the match method in string:

```
var phrase = "Hello John and Hi Anne";
var match = phrase.match("Hello (.*) and Hi (.*)");
console.log(match[1], match[2]);
```